# JS fetch - data disappear or infinite loop

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

This function here has been causing me some trouble for a while.

When printing "res" it shows the object and its fields fine, however when outside of this loop data is then undefined, which is understandable considering the variable is only being initialized within the function.

However if I try to use the setData(field) or setServerUser(field) inside it executes recursively.

I thought the solution to this would be to call either setData(field) or setServerUser(field) outside the loop, though same result.

code:

```
    const [ serverUser, setServerUser ]=useState('')
    const [ data, setData ]=useState('')

    async function fetchProfile(){
        const res = await fetch(
            "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/User/getByEmail", {
            method: "POST",  
            headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"},
            body:JSON.stringify( { email : user.email }  ) } )

        const data = res.json().then((res) => {


            // V both of these causes infinite looping
            // V i dont think this is the right spot to set - but res doesnt exist outside
            //setServerUser(res)
            //setData(res)

            console.log(res) // < this actually prints the object perfectly
        });
        console.log(res) // < equal to undefined here

        // V both of these causes infinite looping
        // V this makes the most sense to me setting here but yet same result
        //setServerUser(data);
        //setData(data)

        console.log("data" + data) // < this returns data[object Promise]
    }

    fetchProfile();
```

Comment: You have a ombination of problems - firstly understanding how to retrieve the result of an async call and secondly how react works when you call a method which calls `setXXX` (from `useState`) during rendering.

Comment: await res.json()

Comment: @Jamiec yes i do, could you provide any suggestions?

Comment: @ABpositive I think we'd need more code to solve the react problem - can you include the relevant parts of your component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to do with useEffect, useState and it overwriting eachother

```
 const [ serverUser, setServerUser ]=useState('')

//3. passing an empty array for on mount (when the page loads)
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/User/getByEmail", {
        method: "POST",  
        headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"},
        body:JSON.stringify( { email : user.email } )
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => { setServerUser(json) })
},[])
```